# jQuery animate left decrement var value returns 0 on chrome and ie

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, window, jquery-animate, width

While developing this webpage i got stuck on this problem:

http://gfn.gfn.pt/

whenever the following function is triggered instead of returning my window width to the left, it returns 0 for each .efect element.

```
function slideFoward(speedB){
    var windowW = $(window).width();
    var d=0;
    $('.efect').each(function(){
        $(this).delay(d).animate({
            'left':'-='+windowW,
            'right':'+='+windowW
        },speedB);
        d=d+50;
    });
}
```

This only happens on chrome, ie and safari. In firefox it roles just fine.

I have researched a lot about this with no answer. If anyone has any clue why this would happen please help.
Thank you VM

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with a little workaround:

instead of using the -= decrement operator I have subtracted the window width to the element.offset().left

```
function slideFoward(speedB){   
    var windowW = $(window).width();
    var d=0;
    $('.efect').each(function(){
        var leftP=windowW-$(this).offset().left;
        $(this).delay(d).animate({
            'right':'+='+windowW,
            'left':''-leftP
        },speedB);
        d=d+50;
    });
}
```